# XML trailing have INvalid data

Tags: xml, xslt

I have Been trying to fix this , my source data adds trailing character after xml root element ,
for example  ,
< root >

< subroot1 >

xml data

< /subroot1 >

< subroot2 >

xml data

< /subroot2 >

< /root > 123243  12121

When I try to specifies the xpath of root  or subroot1 or subroot2 ,  my XSLT gives error that xml have trailing invalid characters. ?

I need helpwith xslt whcih can ignore trailing values anything after root node and read remaining xml and convert xml data into destination .

input data is coming via MQ , so we are using XSLT triggered from spring reads it  .

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: Sounds like your xml is not valid. Try running `xxmllint --noout` yourfile.xml

Comment: Depending on how your data looks there might be ways to parse it as XML, the oldest trick is probably to use it as an external entity in a wrapper document, the cheap trick is to read it in as a string and wrap that string into some root element and parse that new string; as you ask about XSLT it has, in XSLT 3.0, the function `parse-xml-fragment` so you can do e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="parse-xml-fragment(unparsed-text('input.xml'))/*[1]"/>` in the `xsl:initial-template`. All of that of course only works if the file is an external parsed entity. Otherwise XML parsing doesn't work.

Comment: Independent of XSLT there of course parsers (like XmlReader for .NET) that allow settings to parse "fragments" with multiple top level/root elements.

Comment: Where does the broken XML come from? My advice is to fix the problem at its source.

Comment: If you're faced with broken XML, it's always best to work out where it got broken, rather than trying to repair it on arrival.

Comment: Unfortunately source application Build not able to fix this as this is signature of that  .+  Data comes via real time IBM MQ,